# Returning ITERABLE type in Eiffel

Tags: iterable, eiffel

I am trying to return Result  type being ITERABLE[K]. 
All I know is that Iterable inherits from ITERATION_CURSOR, so that I made following unworking code but it doesn't compile.

```
obtainKey (v: V): ITERABLE[G]
    local
        myCollection: ITERABLE [G]
        myCursor:ITERATION_CURSOR[G]
    do
        create {ITERABLE[G]} myCursor
        Result := myCursor
```

My guess is that I have to do something like following, if it was c++ or Java,

```
ITERATION_CURSOR myCursor = new ITERABLE;
```

I don't know. My assumption could be wrong.

How can I do this kind of thing in Eiffel and make above code work?

Comment: It would help if you would explain what you are trying to achieve, what the purpose of the code is, what you expect from it. Just making it "compile" is not the same as making it "work" (in your terms). In particular, why is there an argument `v`, how is the function `obtain_key` supposed to be used, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ITERABLE class is a deferred class (abstract in java) and a deferred class cannot be created. You have to use a class that is not deferred and that inherit from the ITERABLE class. Note that the ITERATION_CURSOR class is also deferred. What to use can change depending of what you need in your implementation. Here is an example using a LINKED_LIST:

```
obtain_key (v:V): ITERABLE[G]
    local
        my_list:LINKED_LIST[G]
    do
        create my_list.make
        Result := my_list
    end
```